# XML to SQL via Datasets

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005, dataset

I've got an XML document and an SQL (MS 2005) table from which I've generated two datasets. The datasets have different schemas with the SQL table basically being a subset of the XML. I'm getting the data into the db as follows:

```
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlStream);
var ta = new TableAdapter();
foreach( var r in dataSet.Tables["MyTable"].Rows )
{
ta.Insert(  DateTime.Parse(r["date1"].ToString()), 
        int.Parse(r["num"].ToString() ), 
        DateTime.Parse(r["date2"].ToString()),
        DateTime.Parse(r["date3"].ToString())
      );
}
```

I'm quite tempted by passing the complete XML to the db and doing the work there but I'm sure there must be a neater way to map the columns between the two datasets and copy the data across in code (particularly not having to convert 'datetime's into strings and back into 'datetime's again). Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a **Hashtable** to store the correspondence datatable column types to 
for e.g.

```
  TypeMap = new Hashtable();
  TypeMap[typeof(UInt64)] = SqlInt64
  TypeMap[typeof(Boolean)] = SqlBoolean                    
  ...
```

and create a function for e.g `GetTypeForData(DataColumn column, object value)`
and return **System.Data.SqlTypes**

No codes but an idea.